# Is there CodeBlock's ctrl-enter shortcut (going to the end of line) equivalent in VisualStudio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Looking for a shortcut that goes to the end of line without using the End key on keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign any keyboard shortcut to the **Edit.LineEnd** command using Visual Studio keyboard options:

[image]