# Is there a shortcut for {End} followed by {Enter}?

Tags: visual-studio, ide

The text editor automatically types the closing brace/bracket/parenthesis/whatever for you, but then to go to the next line I either have to type it again anyway or else I have to press end followed by enter to go to the next line.

Is there a short cut that's easier than having to press end? It's not exactly a convenient key to hit on my laptop.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43925089/is-there-codeblocks-ctrl-enter-shortcut-going-to-the-end-of-line-equivalent-i

Answer (score 1):

You can create the following command with my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension and assign a shortcut to it:

```
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.LineEnd");
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.BreakLine");
```